# Prevent single letter deletes to spam clipboard manager

Tags: vim, clipboard

With `unnamed` clipboard option included, single letter deletes spam my clipboard manager Is it possible to fix this so that single letter deletes (with `x`) are not yanked to clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the `x` command, either to delete to the default register:

```
:nnoremap x ""x
```

or to the black-hole:

```
:nnoremap x "_x
```

With `:help map-expr`, you could extend this to redirect the register only if no `[count]` is given (by evaluating `v:count`), or if no custom register is specified (`v:register`).